# Selecting Table Cells

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, odbc

I'm a beginner at asp.net. 
I have created a table in asp.net and there are timings (E.g. 0700-0750) at the most left column. There are a total of 7 columns and 15 Rows Excluding the Header Row. For each column other than the timings column, it is headed under each day of the week (Mon-Sat). The timeslot uses binary to show booked slots. So does anyone know how to select a tablecell **(NOT GRIDVIEW)** and when it's selected, it'll change the binary from 0 to 1, and when a saved button is clicked that binary will be saved in the database. It'll be great if someone can help me with array codes too since I've not learnt about it.

I'm using visual studios 2010 and microsoft access. Codes are in .aspx and .aspx.vb.
The Database connection I'm using is ODBC connection.

Need help.

***.aspx code***

```
  <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" BackColor="ControlLight" 
BorderWidth="2px" GridLines="Both" Height="156px" 
HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" style="margin-left: 0px" 
Font-Overline="False" EnableViewState="False" >
<asp:TableRow runat="server" BackColor="#FFB18C" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
    BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="15px" Font-Bold="False" 
    Font-Names="Constantia" Font-Size="Large" Height="1.5px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    VerticalAlign="Middle" TableSection="TableHeader">
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Constantia" ForeColor="Black" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="8%">Time</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Names="Constantia" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="15%">Day1 (Mon)</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Names="Constantia" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="15%">Day2 (Tues)</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Names="Constantia" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="15%">Day3 (Weds)</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Names="Constantia" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="15%">Day4 (Thurs)</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Names="Constantia" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="15%">Day5 (Fri)</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" 
        Font-Names="Constantia" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
        Width="8%">Day6 (Sat)</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>


<asp:TableRow runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Height="20px">
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" BorderStyle="Solid"  

       >0700-0750</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid"  ></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select a tablecell per sae, such a thing is not possible. Also, because you are not using a GridView you are also not using server controls. This means that you will have to make your changes completely in Javascript on the client side, save this to something that can be read as a server control and then your save button will post the page back (either as a standard postback or as AJAX) to update the underlying datastore, or alternatively do the whole thing with AJAX.

In short, the way you are trying to approach this is a very complicated and long winded way and I am curious why you would want to do this.

One easier option (you say you are new to ASP.Net so I am assuming that this is really what you want) would be to use a Gridview, put a button or clickable control inside each cell, then use the GridView_RowCommand to detect when a button in a row is pressed, and then read across the row to read the cell that made the change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately the task handed to me requires me to use a table. Other than selecting the tablecell itself, is it possible to like put in a checkbox in each tablecell?